# React- why useEffect called many times (even with condition)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, socket.io

[image: Example of 4 messages]

I work on a simple chat application with react hooks. **In the second useEffect** I need to append the new message to the rest of of them so I will be able to display all of them in the chat. Now i able to append the message only after the useEffect is being called x2 from the array's length. For example: in the forth message the UseEffect will be execute 8 times before the array will be complete.

**notice**: in the useEffect I setAllMessages twice but only one is being execute which is fine depends if it is a reciever of sender (so I dont think this the problem)

```
function Chat() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [userName] = useState(
    JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem("token").split(".")[1])).name
  );
  const [userTyping, setUserTyping] = useState(null);
  const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("join", userName);
    socket.on("chat-message", data => {
      toast(`Hello ${data}`);
    });
    socket.on("user-joined", data => {
      toast(`${data} joined the chat`);
    });
  }, [userName]);

  useEffect(() => {                             // the problem is here
    function handleAllMessages(data) {
      setAllMessages([...allMessages, data]);
      console.log(allMessages);
    }
    socket.on("broadcast-message", data => {
      handleAllMessages(data);
    });
    socket.on("my-message", data => {
      data["userName"] = "You";
      handleAllMessages(data);
    });
  }, [allMessages]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("who-typing", data => {
      setUserTyping(data);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setUserTyping(null);
      }, 2500);
    });
  }, [userTyping]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("user-disconnected", data => {
      toast(`${data} left the chat`);
    });
  }, []);

  function handleChat(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (message.trim() === "") return toast.warn("not valid message");
    socket.emit("user-message", message, userName);
    setMessage("");
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
    socket.emit("typing", userName);
  }

  return (...
```

Comment: I believe you don't have to be using `useEffect` at all in order for you to achieve that, the `socket.on` will invoke your callback functions when ever the network intercepts a message coming to the channel you pass in as the first Arg.

While invoking the callback will be updating you messages since `handleAllMessages` will do the job and set the new state which will make your component re-render anyway.

Comment: @SultanH. so where should I call `handleAllMessages` or `socket.on` for that matter?

Comment: After thinkin about it, remove the `allMessages` from the array you are passing as a second argument to the `useEffect` method, it'll make it act like `componentDidMount` this way. that would hopefully do the job.

Comment: without a second argument the `useEffect` called number of times. with a second argument as an empty array, the allMessages state dosnt even change

Comment: I'm not sure why having the empty array will prevent `allMessages` from getting updated, I don't wanna question the `socket` connection, but, if you can verify the socket connection is established successfully then we can try a hack-around this problem -Preventing adding the message if it's already there-

Comment: I just added the example above. so you can see that every new message the first useeffect return an empty array for the first time it runs. this why an empty array as a second argument give nothing (because it makes it run only one time)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205099/discussion-between-sultan-h-and-gil-nuriel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hooks the right way to setAllMessages (in this case) is to pass the oldArray like this...

```
setAllMessages(allMessages => [...allMessages, data]);
```

and inside the use effect pass empty array as a second argument instead `[allMessages]`

this fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason while the second `useEffect` will be executed multiple times -in face I suppose infinitely-, is because you are telling it to execute each time `allMessages` change, since it's in the Array -the second argument for `useEffect`.

Passing that array with `allMessages` in it will cause the `useEffect` to re-run every time `allMessages` change, which is actually what you are doing inside the `useEffect` when you are calling the `handleAllMessages` function.

[Read about this.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)